# Google Cloud Build GitHub App - auto trigger for all projects in organization

Tags: github, google-cloud-build

Up until a few weeks ago, when installing the Google Cloud Build GitHub app in a GitHub organization, it was possible to specify that all GitHub projects within that organization would create a build trigger.

Yesterday I noticed that this no longer happens, and new projects added to the GitHub organizations don't trigger a build and I can see a message on the specific commit saying that "this repository is not mapped to a Google Cloud platform project".

Is this an intentional change in spec - so one needs to manually link every new repo via the Console/API - or something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

yes. for a new project, you have to manually set up on the cloud build page by "Connect repository". then you can use gcp cli comamnd set the trigger,

```
gcloud beta builds triggers create github
```